# Como adicionar uma variável do javascript no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu quero pegar a `variável` do `vetor` que crio no `JS` e armazenar o conteúdo dela em uma do `PHP`.

```
<?php
       print("<SCRIPT language=javascript>  
              vetor_dados[$cont] ="text";
       </SCRIPT>"); 
$conteudo = vetor_dados;
?>
```

Como deveria fazer?

Obs:
 A maneira de usar o, ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 'valor';
</script>
<?php
    $x = "<script>document.write(x)</script>";
    echo $x;
?>
```

Faz com que o `$x` mostre <`script>document.write(x)</script>` e não o conteudo do `JS`;

Imagem de como aparece da forma acima: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não e possível deste jeito. Precisa entender o conceito: HTML e JS são linguagem *client* o que significa que a execução deles é feita no seu computador. O PHP é um linguagem servidor, o que significa que o "motor" PHP está no servidor, e não no seu computador.

Do ponto de vista cronológico, o navegador requisita a página, o motor PHP analisa a requisição e gera o código e envia de volta para o navegador, então o PHP é encerrado. A página viaja pela internet, chega ao computador do usuário e a partir deste momento o navegador renderiza o HTML recebido e executa o Javascript.

Significa que a parte

```
 <?php $conteudo = vector_dados ?>
```

é executado no servidor, e que o resto (HTML, CSS e JS) é executado, DEPOIS, na maquina do usuário.

Para recuperar os dados do Javascript com o PHP, é preciso re-enviar os dados para o servidor.

Comment: Ou seja @Peter, não é possível executar dessa maneira que pretendo?

Answer (score 0):

Vai precisar fazer desta forma:

```
<SCRIPT language=javascript>  
    var vetor_dados ="text";
</SCRIPT>

<?php
    $conteudo = "<script>document.write(vetor_dados)</script>";

    echo $conteudo;
?>
```

Comment: Então @Otto, conforme eu coloquei na edição, essa maneira não mostra o conteudo da variavel do JS e sim o text: `<script>document.write(vetor_dados)</script>` que foi atribuido no PHP

Comment: acabei de efetuar o teste aqui e ele imprime text e não <script>document.write(vetor_dados)</script>

Comment: @Alexandre pode efetuar o teste

Comment: Sim @Otto, acabei de reefetuar o teste e acabou dando a mesma! Irei editar a publicação com uma imagem mostrando!

Comment: Otto, no caso que vc coloca, a segunda parte (PHP) vai ser executada ANTES da primeira.

Comment: O mais engraçado é funcionar ....

Comment: É lógico que funciona. Não precisa nem testar...